# "Complete" classification using decision tree

Tags: r, cart, rpart

While exploring the examples from "[Practical Data Science with R](http://www.manning.com/zumel/)", I am using a decision tree to classify the spambase dataset. It works fine, but I am trying to "abuse" the model in order to have accuracy of 1. I know it is meaningless, and that my code example skips the train/test split, but this is merely for educational reasons.

I tried to lower the control parameter `cp` to as low as 0, and also to allow any split by lowering `minsplit` to 1, but I still get accuracy of 0.9989133. Can you please help me? This is my code:

```
require(rpart)
spam.data <- read.table(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WinVector/zmPDSwR/master/Spambase/spamD.tsv",
    header=T,
    sep='\t')
spam.features <- setdiff(colnames(spam.data),list('rgroup','spam'))
spam.formula <- as.formula(paste('spam=="spam"',
                           paste(spam.features,collapse=' + '),
                           sep=' ~ '))
spam.CART.model <- rpart(spam.formula,
                         data=spam.data,
                         method='class',
                         control=rpart.control(minsplit=1,
                                               cp=0))
spam.data$pred.CART <- predict(spam.CART.model,
                                   newdata=spam.data,
                                   type='class')
c.m <- table(actual=spam.data$spam=='spam',
             prediction=spam.data$pred.CART==T)
accuracy <- (c.m[1,1] + c.m[2,2]) /
  (c.m[1,1] + c.m[1,2] + c.m[2,1] + c.m[2,2])
```

and my results are:

```
> c.m
       prediction
actual  FALSE TRUE
  FALSE  2786    2
  TRUE      3 1810
> accuracy
[1] 0.9989133
```

I hope my code lines and other formatting will work. I am not a very experienced user...

Thanks!

Comment: Try to increase the depth of the tree (defaults to "maxdepth = 30" which is the maximum possible value on a 32 bit system though). Please note that this forum is about statistics, not about programming or using R.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, and indeed the maximum depth is 30, which is reached by me tree...

Comment: @MichaelM BTW - what parameter would you use for achieving the same goal with Logistic Regression?

Comment: If you don't want to take into account the object's row number as covariable, you generally can't expect perfect fit, namely if the response is different but the rest is exactly the same. Then neither logistic regression nor tree nor any other classification model can help.